# Update Drupal Application with an external DB script

Tags: database, drupal

I’m trying to update my Drupal application with an external script writing directly in the MySQL DB, I only need to modify one field of one specific datatype. I see it in a table named field_data_field_FIELDNAME but when I update this the application doesn’t change. I need to modify something else? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to change the field's value, try modifying both field_data_field_FIELDNAME and field_revision_field_FIELDNAME, then clear all cache.

Note that you do not actually need to clear all cache if you know what you need to clear, e.g. to clear the field's value for a particular node, you can use `cache_clear_all('field:node:[your nid here]', 'cache_field');`

If your are trying to change more than the field's value, I suggest you do it through the [Field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7).